# Como obtener el Documento de un campo en cloud FireStore

Tags: firebase, angular4

espero me puedan ayudar, llevo buscando mucho tiempo y no he logrado nada.
Los Campos de "x" Documento lo agregue en una tabla en HTML, y he agregado dos botones, editar y eliminar, lo que quiero es obtener el Documento de donde proviene el Campo de la fila del boton, por fin poderlo eliminar. Es como hacer un get del index de el Campo. 
Estoy usando Angular y AngularFire2

Provider

```
private sprintCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Sprint>;
  private itemDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<any>;
  sprints: Sprint[] = [];  
  item:any[]=[];

  constructor( private afs: AngularFirestore  ) { 
    this.sprintCollection = this.afs.collection<Sprint>('Sprints');
  }

  getSprint(value:string){
    this.sprintCollection = this.afs.collection('Sprints', ref => ref.where('Application', '==', value) )
    return this.sprintCollection.valueChanges();
 }

  getSprints(){
    return this.sprintCollection.valueChanges();
   }

   addSprint( sprint:Sprint){
     return this.sprintCollection.add(sprint);
   }
```

Componente

```
this._sp.getSprints().subscribe(data=>{
      for(let key$ in data){
        let h =data[key$]
        h.key$ = key$
        this.sprintGrid.push(data[key$]);
      }
    });
```

HTML

```
<table class="table table-hover  table-sm">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col">Sprint</th>
                  <th scope="col">Aplication</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let sprint of sprintGrid; let i = index">
                  <td>{{ sprintGrid[i].Sprint }}</td>
                  <td>{{ sprintGrid[i].Application }}</td>
                  <td>
                      <button kendoButton style="background-color: #ffc107; color:white"  class="col-lg-4" [icon]="'edit'" ></button>
                      <button kendoButton style="background-color: #dc3545; color:white" (click)="delete(sprintGrid[i].key$)"   class="col-lg-4" [icon]="'delete'" ></button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: Puedes agregar más detalles a tu pregunta... estoy trabajando con un proyecto en Angular5 junto con Firestore y quiza te pueda ayudar, pero la verdad no entiendo que es lo que quieres hacer.